# Find bases of the kernel and image of T, and thus determine the rank

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find the matrix of the given linear transformation T with respect to the given basis.

Determine whether T is an isomorphism. If T isn't an isomorphism find bases of the kernel and image of T, and thus determine the rank of T.

T(M) = M$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ - $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$M from $U^{2x2}$ to $U^{2x2}$

with respect to the standard basis $\mathfrak A$ $\text = (1, t, t^2)$
Which is the basis for all second degree polynomials.

I know that T is not an isomorphism because $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ are in the kernel.

And I have found A = $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\2&0&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I'm unsure how to find the image and rank of T. There is a similar problem posted. But it has different bases.

Comment: Is $U^{2\times 2}$ the space of $2\times 2$ matrices?

Comment: "I have found $A$" But you haven't *defined* $A$ – what is $A$ supposed to mean?

Comment: $U^{2x2}$ are all upper triangular matrices

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $U^{2\times 2}$ is the space of $2\times 2$ matrices. Your map $T:U^{2\times 2}\to U^{2\times 2}$ is $T(X)=AX-XA$ where
$$
A = 
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
It sounds like you're trying to represent $T$ as a matrix. To do so, we need a basis for $U^{2\times 2}$. The standard basis is
\begin{align*}
E_{11} &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right] &
E_{12} &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right] &
E_{21} &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right] &
E_{22} &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcrcrcrcrc}
T(E_{11}) &=&
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} & = &
0\cdot E_{11} &+& 2\cdot E_{12} &+& 0\cdot E_{21} &+& 0\cdot E_{22} \\
T(E_{12}) &=&
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} &=&
0\cdot E_{11} &+& 0\cdot E_{12} &+& 0\cdot E_{21} &+& 0\cdot E_{22} \\
T(E_{21}) &=&
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
&=&
-2\cdot E_{11} &+& 0\cdot E_{12} &+& 0\cdot E_{21} &+& 2\cdot E_{22} \\
T(E_{22}) &=&
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&=&
0\cdot E_{11} &+& -2\cdot E_{12} &+& 0\cdot E_{21} &+& 0\cdot E_{22} 
\end{array}
This shows that our matrix representation of $T$ is
$$
[T]=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now, use your favorite method to compute bases for the null space and column space of $[T]$.

The vectors 
\begin{align*}
\langle 1,0,0,1\rangle && \langle0,1,0,0\rangle
\end{align*}
form a basis for the null space of $[T]$. This tells us that the matrices
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcrcrcrcrc}
1\cdot E_{11} &+& 0\cdot E_{12} &+& 0\cdot E_{21} &+& 1\cdot E_{22} &=&
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
0\cdot E_{11} &+& 1\cdot E_{12} &+& 0\cdot E_{21} &+& 0\cdot E_{22} &=&
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{array}
form a basis for the kernel of $T$.

Can you find a basis for the column space of $[T]$ and use this to find a basis for the image of $T$?

Comment: the basis for this problem $= (1, t, t^2)$

Comment: What is $t$ here?

Comment: the first degree term of all 2nd degree polynomials.

Comment: How is that basis relevant to this problem?

Comment: Thank you Brian, I misread the bases. @Brian Fitzpatrick